# Web-Scraping con python en tablas dinamicas./ No consigo que reconozca la tabla a pesar de ser la correcta

Tags: html, python, eventos

```
     **La intención es consultar en una página web las pistas libres de padel de un club e incluso recibir notificación cuando queden slots libres de las reservas.**
    
        from selenium import webdriver
        import pandas as pd
        from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
        from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
        from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

importamos todo lo necesario

```
    *#Configurar selenium*
        driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
        url = 'https://hallofpadel.com/booking/'
        driver.get(url)
```

> Esperar hasta que la tabla esté presente en la página. Aqui es donde tengo l problema ya que no consigo detectar la tabla en la pagina web

```
        try:

          
table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'fc-agenda-slots'))  
            )
            print("La tabla está presente en la página.")
        except:
            print("La tabla no se encontró en la página.")
```

> ## Inicializar listas para almacenar datos

```
        platz_1 = []
        platz_2 = []
        platz_3 = []
        zentral_1 = []
        zentral_2 = []
```

> ## Procesar la tabla si se encuentra

```
        if table:
            # Obtener todas las filas de la tabla
            rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
            # Iterar sobre las filas de la tabla
            for row in rows[1:]:
                # Obtener las celdas de la fila
                cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
                # Procesar cada fila si tiene suficientes celdas
                if len(cells) >= 5:
                    platz_1.append(cells[0].text)
                    platz_2.append(cells[1].text)
                    platz_3.append(cells[2].text)
                    zentral_1.append(cells[3].text)
                    zentral_2.append(cells[4].text)
                else:
                    print("Skipping row with insufficient data")
```

> ## Crear un DataFrame con los datos recopilados

```
            df = pd.DataFrame({
                'platz_1': platz_1,
                'platz_2': platz_2,
                'platz_3': platz_3,
                'zentral_1': zentral_1,
                'zentral_2': zentral_2
            })
```

> ## Mostrar el DataFrame

```
            print(df)
        
        else:
            print("No se encontró la tabla en la página.")
```

> ## Cerrar el navegador

```
        driver.quit()
```

Es la primera vez que interacciono con Python haciendo web Scraping. He conseguido hacer esto entre tutoriales y Gpt pero no consigo resolverlo.

Comment: Ocurre que estás intentando acceder a los elementos de OTRA PAGINA, que es la que está renderizando el iframe. Selenium solo renderiza el documento principal, si quieres acceder al documento del iframe, debes cambiar de contexto (como si cambiarás de pestaña). Selenium ofrece varias formas de hacerlo : [Working with IFrames and frames](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/)

Comment: O si prefieres con Selenium visita la [url](https://sport.nubapp.com/web/index.php#/bookings) que está renderizando el iframe y obtén los elementos que deseas